# Quarkus Panache .project() doesnt work with null values

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

## TL:DR

Is there a way of getting null safe projections with panache .project() so i can use @ProjectedFieldName in my Records even if the related Field is null.

## STATUS QUO

Ive got my Rep and my User Entity aswell as the Record:

```java
class UserRepository implements PanacheRepository<User> {
  public UserRecord findRecordByUsername(String username) {
    return find("username", username).project(UserRecord.class).firstResultOptional().orElse(null);
  }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User extends BaseEntity {

  @NotEmpty
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String username;

  @ManyToOne
  private Address address;
}
```

```java
@RegisterForReflection
public record UserRecord(
  String username,
  @ProjectedFieldName("address.name") String name
) {
}
```

Lets assume i have a User in my DB with username = test and the address = null.

## THE PROBLEM

Now if i want to get the userRecord by the username i get as return null because the find().project() creates the following sql:

```sql
select
        b1_0.username,
        t1_0.name 
    from
        User b1_0 
    join
        Address t1_0 
            on t1_0.id=b1_0.address_id 
    where
        b1_0.username=? fetch first ? rows only
```

The Problem here ist the "**join**".

The "**join**" should be a left join or atleast it should be configurable so we can work with null values. But i didnt found any evidances of being able to do so.

And this is not even a unique situation, where ive got null values in my entities. This is mostly the case in bigger entities.

And yes i could write the find in HQL and just put the left join there. But thats not practicable if you wanne do it in a bigger Project with entities with dozents of properties.

## QUESTION

How can i get the response of the UserRecord even if the Address is null?

Thanks for every helpful comment.